# C# .net http | How to get objects layers deep from API

Tags: c#, json.net

I learned how to get information from an API using the microsoft docs, the microsoft docs don't show how to get nested/layers deep objects. The only video I found that showed how to do it did it something like this. However I can't get it to work, receiving only an error stating this:

```
"Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Dashboard.Weather' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly."
```

Any help is appreciated, i'm trying to get the "Weather.description", here's my sample code:

```
public class Weather
{
    public string Description{ get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public Weather Weather { get; set; }
}

public static class ApiHelper
{
    static string city_id = "CITY_ID";
    static string api_key = "API_KEY";
    public static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    public static void InitializeClient()
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri($"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id={city_id}&APPID={api_key}");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }

    public static async Task<Weather> GetProductAsync()
    {
        Product product = null;
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("");
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            product = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Product>();
        }
        return product.Weather;

    }
}

    async void SetLabelText()
    {
        var weather = await ApiHelper.GetProductAsync();

        descriptionLabel.Text = $"Description: {weather.Description}";
    }
```

The response from the API is formatted as follows

```
{"coord":{"lon":-89.59,"lat":41.56},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":279.27,"feels_like":275.4,"temp_min":278.15,"temp_max":280.37,"pressure":1027,"humidity":74},"visibility":16093,"wind":{"speed":3.1,"deg":200},"clouds":{"all":1},"dt":1576951484,"sys":{"type":1,"id":3561,"country":"US","sunrise":1576934493,"sunset":1576967469},"timezone":-21600,"id":4915397,"name":"Walnut","cod":200}
```

Comment: That is not valid json which is most likely your initial problem. Is that really what the api responds with?

Comment: baxorr could you post the Product model? based upon the error, it's likely your product model doesn't assume your weather is a list.

Comment: @BillKeller the `Product` model is posted and `Weather` is not a list but since the json is invalid we don't know if it is supposed to be. Does it make sense to have a collection of weather items for a given lat and lon? Maybe, I'm not familiar with that api. And if they require an api key over GET and don't use TLS I never will be.

Comment: ah, missed that, well, even if the json was correct, Weather needs to be a List<Weather> on the Product model.

Comment: @Crowcoder My apologies, I don't know if I posted the wrong snippet. I've added the full unformatted response of the API.

What I want to get is the description within the weather

Comment: @BillKeller I've already tried using a list but couldn't get it to work, I must have done something wrong then :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Product` model does not correctly align with the json you are receiving.

The json you've post has weather as a list, but `Product` assumes it will just be an object. The json parser, then, correctly fails when seeing it is an array in the actual json instead of a JSON object.

The fix should be simple; `Product.Weather` should be of type `List<Weather>` (or `IEnumerable<Weather>` or `Weather[]`, whichever fits your needs).

Comment: Wow it really was that simple! Thanks Bill, I hope you have a great day!